# Trouble turning XML into HTML table with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, xml, xml-parsing

I know there's a lot of other questions out there that deal with this topic, but none that specifically address my problem.

I'm taking an XML file, parsing it with Jquery and turning it into an HTML table. On the page visually, it looks good; the table looks like it should. But in actuality, Jquery is doing something weird with the html.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<wsmenu>
<cat id="snacks">
    <item>
        <desc>marta&#8217;s fresh tortillas &amp; camp bread, pit master fat</desc>
        <price>4</price>
        <wood>m</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>smoked almonds, chile salt</desc>
        <price>4</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>smoked marinated olives</desc>
        <price>4</price>
        <wood>o</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>crispy potatoes, smoked garlic aioli</desc>
        <price>6</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>smoked artichokes, lemon and parmesan</desc>
        <price>9</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>smoked hummus, pit master fat camp bread &amp; tortilla chips</desc>
        <price>8</price>
        <wood>m</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>smoked whitefish dip, fresh tortilla chips</desc>
        <price>9</price>
        <wood>o</wood>
    </item>
</cat>
<cat id="salads">
    <item>
        <desc>smoked chicory, chicken chicharron, mustard-red wine vinaigrette, provolone</desc>
        <price>8</price>
        <wood>m</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>3 kale salad, celery greens, guanciale, smoked pepita, manchego</desc>
        <price>8</price>
        <wood>m</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>hickory braised spelt, smoked almond pesto &amp; tomato</desc>
        <price>8</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>beet and fresh ricotta salad, smoked pistachios</desc>
        <price>8</price>
        <wood>m</wood>
    </item>
</cat>
<cat id="sandwiches">
    <item>
        <desc>pulled pork, bbq, house cole slaw, mustard &amp; pickles</desc>
        <price>8</price>
        <wood>o</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>chopped beef, house mustard &amp; pickles</desc>
        <price>8</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>woodshed burger, chopped beef, todays sausage, smoked cheddar, traditional garnish</desc>
        <price>11</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
</cat>
<cat id="simple plates">
    <item>
        <desc>brisket stuffed piquillo peppers, bone broth &amp; cotija</desc>
        <price>9</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>local acorn squash, tuaca, dark brown sugar, smoked pepper hollandaise</desc>
        <price>8</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>today&#8217;s sausage, house mustard &amp; pickles</desc>
        <price>8</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>pea tendrils, smoked chilies, citrus &amp; hickory butter</desc>
        <price>8</price>
        <wood>o</wood>
    </item>
</cat>
<cat id="tacos">
    <item>
        <desc>brisket stuffed piquillo peppers, bone broth &amp; cotija</desc>
        <price>9</price>
        <wood>m</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>local acorn squash, tuaca, dark brown sugar, smoked pepper hollandaise</desc>
        <price>9</price>
        <wood>m</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>today&#8217;s sausage, house mustard &amp; pickles</desc>
        <price>10</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>pea tendrils, smoked chilies, citrus &amp; hickory butter</desc>
        <price>9</price>
        <wood>m</wood>
    </item>
</cat>
<cat id="traditional q">
    <item>
        <desc>beef ribs</desc>
        <price>12/lb</price>
        <wood>o</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>pork ribs</desc>
        <price>12/lb</price>
        <wood>p</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>smoked beef tenderloin</desc>
        <sub>served cold</sub>
        <price>11</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
</cat>
<cat id="new q">
    <item>
        <desc>smoked red fish enpapillote, vegetables of the season</desc>
        <price>19</price>
        <wood>o</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>game bird, wood braised spelt &amp; smoked artichokes</desc>
        <price>21</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>fancy mushrooms of the season, 4 chiles, polenta, vin cotta &amp; hen egg</desc>
        <price>18</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>bowl of ramen noodles, bone broth, pulled pork, chiles, &amp; quail egg</desc>
        <price>15</price>
        <wood>p</wood>
    </item>
</cat>
<cat id="dining with friends">
    <sub>please allow 30 minutes, feeds 4 people</sub>
    <item>
        <desc>16 hour smoked beef shin, fresh ricotta, chile, smoked oil borracho beans, 3 kale salad</desc>
        <price>75</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>open fire paella of mussels, clams, shrimp rabbit-rattlesnake sausage, game bird, fennel aioli</desc>
        <price>75</price>
        <wood>m</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>60 oz. bistecca alla fiorentina, crispy potatoes</desc>
        <price>90</price>
        <wood>m</wood>
    </item>
</cat>
<cat id="sides">
    <item>
        <desc>fresh chips</desc>
        <price>5</price>
        <wood>m</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>smoked Loaded baked potato</desc>
        <sub>add pork or beef $3</sub>
        <price>5</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>borracho beans</desc>
        <price>5</price>
        <wood>h</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>mexican corn</desc>
        <price>4</price>
        <wood>m</wood>
    </item>
    <item>
        <desc>confit potato salad, mint, red pepper, crispy garlic</desc>
        <price>4</price>
        <wood>m</wood>
    </item>
</cat>
</wsmenu>
```

Here's the Jquery:

```
function parseXML(xml){
$(xml).find("cat").each(function()
{
  $(".menu").append("<table class='mnutbl'><tr><th>"+$(this).attr("id")+"</th></tr>");

$(this).find("item").each(function()
{
    $(".menu").append("<tr class='mnutbl'><td>"+$(this).find("wood").text()+
    "</td><td>"+$(this).find("desc").text()+
    "</a></td><td>"+$(this).find("price").text()+
    "</td></tr></table>")});
});
};
```

Current output:

```
Jquery is writing <table> and <th> with attribute "id" for each <cat> tag, then separate <tr> for each <item> tag (these <tr>'s are NOT contained in the <table>), like so:
<table class="mnutbl">
 <tr>
  <th>Snacks</th>
 </tr>
</table>
<tr>
 <td>m</td>
 <td>marta's fresh...</td>
 <td>4</td>
</tr>
etc.......
```

Two part question:

1. Each `<cat>` tag needs to be its own `<table>` and the `<item>` tags in each `<cat>` need to be table rows WITHIN that `<table>`. Am I doing something wrong with my Jquery code?
2. Some of the `<desc>` values need to be links to images, but not all of them. If I added `<imgurl>` to only some of the `<item>` tags in the XML file, how could I properly write that into the table as a `<a href="...>` using Jquery?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not appending your table rows to the table, but to the `.menu`. Try this instead:

```
$(".menu").find('table').last().append("<tr ..... ");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/fppfX/

tucuxi is also right, however. Don't append the closing `</table>` tag.

Comment: There may be more efficient ways to write this code, of course, but the above should be the simplest change to solve your problem.

Comment: This is why I love Stack Overflow! Thank you very much to both you AND tucuxi! Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes!

Any idea about the 2nd part of my question?

Comment: That's a bit of a different problem, and you have no sample code for it. I'd recommend posting that as a separate question (after you've tried to tackle it yourself, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the last `</table>` from your inner `$(".menu").append`, and add it to the outer one. JQuery's append places elements into each other - so it makes sense to place well-formed table-rows into well-formed tables, instead of attempting to close the tables with each table-row.

Also, keep a reference to the table as follows:
function parseXML(xml){

```
$(xml).find("cat").each(function() {
  var table = $("<table class='mnutbl'><tr><th>"+$(this).attr("id")+
    "</th></tr></table>");
  $(".menu").append(table);

  $(this).find("item").each(function(){
    table.append("<tr class='mnutbl'><td>"+$(this).find("wood").text()+
      "</td><td>"+$(this).find("desc").text()+
      "</a></td><td>"+$(this).find("price").text()+
      "</td></tr>")});
  });
};
```

The browser is then adding all the extra table-start-tags to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

You are always appending to `.menu` but you have to append the items to the table. To do so either give the table an ID to have it identified. Or even simpler: store it into a variable and first append all rows and afterwards append the whole table to the page.

```
function parseXML( xml ) {
    $( xml ).find( 'cat' ).each( function() {
        var id = $( this ).attr( 'id' );
        var table = $( '<table class="mnutbl" id="' + id  + '"><tr><th>' + id  + '</th></tr></table>' );

        $( this ).find( 'item' ).each( function() {
            table.append( '<tr><td>' +
                $( this ).find('wood').text() +
                '</td><td>' + $( this ).find( 'desc' ).text() +
                '</a></td><td>' + $( this ).find( 'price' ).text() +
                '</td></tr>' );
        } );

        $( '.menu' ).append( table );
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution of this problem would be to use XSL transformations (XSLT), a language which is specifically created for the tasks like this one.

The language and the logic behind the transformations is quite simple and easy to learn. You can check it out here:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: XSLT is not that easy to learn. Moreover, every browser has a few buggy quirks with it that they've not bothered to fix due to its lack of popularity. I recommend avoiding it.

Comment: I'm actually very open to learning how to do that, but I'm on a tight deadline with this website and don't really have time to learn something new. But one of these days I'd like to dive into XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see with your code is that initially you're closing the table tag right within your search for the "item" tag.

```
function parseXML(xml){
$(xml).find("cat").each(function()
{
  $(".menu").append("<table class='mnutbl'><tr><th>"+$(this).attr("id")+"</th></tr>");

$(this).find("item").each(function()
{
    $(".menu").append("<tr class='mnutbl'><td>"+$(this).find("wood").text()+
        "</td><td>"+$(this).find("desc").text()+
        "</a></td><td>"+$(this).find("price").text()+
        "</td></tr>")});
    });
$(".menu").append("</table>");
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I actually answered the second part of my question.

Using the same XML file, only this time some of the `<item>` tags now have an attribute of `imgurl=""` which contain a relative url to a photo.

I altered my JQuery function `parseXML` to include a conditional that checks if the attribute `imgurl` exists and then create an link to it around the item description

Here's the code:

```
function parseXML(xml){
$(xml).find("cat").each(function()
{
$(".menu").append("<table class='mnutbl'><tr><th>"+$(this).attr("id")+"</th></tr>");

$(this).find("item").each(function()
{
    var $x;
    var $image = $(this).attr("imgurl");
    if ($image == null) {
        $x = $(this).find("desc").text();
    }
    else {
        $x = "<a href='"+$image+"'>"+$(this).find("desc").text()+"</a>"
    }
    $(".menu").find("table").last().append("<tr><td>"+$(this).find("wood").text()+
    "</td><td>"+$x+"</td><td>"+$(this).find("price").text()+
    "</td></tr>")
});
$(".menu").append("</table>");
});
};
```

I'm very proud of myself since I'm still pretty new to this level of programming (which is probably very basic for most of y'all), and I managed to do this all by myself with w3c and jQuery website references.